# Calling a function on all component dynanically generate from list

Tags: react-native

I am building a dynamic list of input components and when the user presses the submit button I would like to validate the input in every component by calling a function on each component so that each component can visually show that it has failed validation.

My component is "RegularTextInput" and I build it like this where it is used:

```
{carRegistrationNumbers.map((value, index) => (
    <RegularTextInput
        // add function to a list?
    />
);
```

I am new to React and React Native. How would I go about doing this? In my "RegularTextInput" how would I declare that function? And in the caller, should I maintain a list/array of all the components or functions somehow, so that I can call the function in all components when I press my submit button? Am I on the wrong path completely here :)

Thank you
Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not using forms thus the

```
onSubmitEditing
```

is never called. My solution was to use

```
onEndEditing
```

and then call

```
Keyboard.dismiss()
```

to trigger the onEndEditing. That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would solve your problem. You have to declare the function inside the component itself.

```
const RegularTextInput = () => {
     const validateHandler = () => {
       if (!name.length) {
         setError("Can't be blank.")
       }
     }
return (
  <TextInput {...otherProps} onSubmitEditing={validateHandler} />
)}
```

Comment: onSubmitEditing is never called, I am guessing because I am not using a form?

Comment: Okay. So do you want to check the condition on every letter change?